# Tedious Inequality from Spanish Olympiad

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, contest-math

Let $n\geq 2$ an integer. Find the least value of $\gamma$ such that for any positive real numbers $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ with $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=1$ and any real $y_1+y_2+...+y_n=1$ and $0\leq y_1,y_2,...,y_n\leq \frac{1}{2}$ the following inequality holds:
$$x_1x_2...x_n\leq \gamma \left(x_1y_1+x_2y_2+...+x_ny_n\right)$$

The official solution is near to inconprehensible, however one student got a relatively easy solution which is not shown.

I tried many things but I couldn't get any further. Any help is preciated.

**Edit**: Since there is some confusion $\gamma$ depens on $n$. So that for every $n$ $\gamma$ is diferent.

Comment: what's the gist of the official solution ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Defining a function making huge varible changes and aplying Jesen's Inequality. It's a "usual" technique, thedious and ugly, but I heard from other students that it can be done far easier than official solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $n$. Let's call $\gamma$ *good* if it satisfies the desired inequalities, i.e., if for all $x_1,\ldots,x_n\geq 0$ with $\sum x_i=1$ and for all $0\leq y_1,\ldots,y_n\leq 1/2$ with $\sum y_i=1$, we have
$$x_1\cdots x_n\leq\gamma(x_1y_1+\cdots+x_ny_n)$$

Suppose $x_1\leq x_2\leq\cdots\leq x_n$, and that $0\leq y_1,\ldots,y_n\leq 1/2$ satisfy $\sum y_i=1$.

We can think of the sum $\sum x_iy_i$ as a "weighted average" of the $x_i$. Since $x_i\leq x_j$ for $i\leq j$, if we pass some of the weight of $x_j$ to $x_i$ this "weighted average" will decrease.

More precisely, let $p=1/2-y_1$. Then
\begin{align*}
x_1\frac{1}{2}+x_2\frac{1}{2}&=x_1(y_1+p)+x_2(\sum_{i=2}^ny_i-p)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i+p(x_1-x_2)\leq\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i
\end{align*}

Therefore, $\gamma$ is good if and only if for all $0\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq\cdots\leq x_n$ with $\sum x_i=1$,
$$x_1\cdots x_n\leq\frac{\gamma}{2}(x_1+x_2)$$
Moreover, it is easy enough (by considering permutations of the $x_i$) to see that the condition $x_1\leq x_2\leq\cdots\leq x_n$ is not necessary.

We now need to simplify the product $x_1\cdots x_n$. We need the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** Suppose $0\leq y<z\leq 1$, and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then there exists $w\in[y,z]$ with $y+kz=w^{k+1}$ and $yz^k\leq w^{k+1}$.
>
> *Proof:* Consider the function:
>   $$f(\epsilon)=(y+\epsilon)(z-\frac{\epsilon}{k})^k.$$
>   Then
>   $$f'(\epsilon)=-\left(z-\frac{\epsilon}{k}\right)^{k-1}(y+\epsilon)+\left(z-\frac{\epsilon}{k}\right)^k$$
>   So $f'(\epsilon_0)=0$ if and only if $y+\epsilon_0=z-\frac{\epsilon_0}{k}$, or equivalently $\epsilon_0=\frac{k}{k+1}(z-y)$, which is positive. If $k=1$ then this is a (global) maximum for $f$, obviously. If $k\geq 2$,
>   $$f''(\epsilon)=\frac{k-1}{k}\left(z-\frac{\epsilon}{k}\right)^{k-2}(y+\epsilon)-2\left(z-\frac{\epsilon}{k}\right)^{k-1}$$
>   and so $f''(\frac{k}{k+1}(z-y))<0$. Again, this point is a (global) maximum for $f$. Therefore, $w=y+\epsilon_0$ has the desired properties.

Applying the lemma inductively on the product $x_3\cdots x_n$ (from right to left), we can find some $z\in[0,1]$ with $(n-2)z=x_3+\cdots+x_n$ and $x_3\cdots x_n\leq z^{n-2}$. Also, applying the lemma on the product $x_1x_2$ we find $y$ with $x_1+x_2=2y$ and $x_1x_2\leq y^2$.

Therefore, $\gamma$ is good if and only if for every $0\leq y,z\leq 1$ with $2y+(n-2)z=1$ (in particular, $0\leq y\leq 1/2$), we have
$$y^2z^{(n-2)}\leq\gamma y.$$

If $n=2$ then the minimum good $\gamma$ is $1/2$, so let's assume $n\geq 3$.

Since are considering $z=\frac{1-2y}{n-2}$, and , we simply have to maximize the function $g(y)=y\left(\frac{1-2y}{n-2}\right)^{n-2}$ in the interval $[0,1/2]$.

Note that $g(0)=g(1/2)=0$ and that $g$ is positive on $[0,1/2]$. Thus if the equation $g'(y)=0$ has only one solution, this will necessarily be the maximum of $g$ on $[0,1/2]$

So let's calculate

$$g'(y)=\left(\frac{1-2y}{n-2}\right)^{n-2}-2y\left(\frac{1-2y}{n-2}\right)^{n-3}$$

The unique solution to $g'(y)=0$ is $y_0=\frac{1}{2(n-1)}$, which is in $[0,1/2]$ just as we wanted, on which we obtain
$$g(y_0)=\frac{1}{2(n-1)}\left(\frac{1-2\frac{1}{2(n-1)}}{n-2}\right)^{n-2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}$$
Therefore the minimum good $\gamma$ is $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}$.

---

**EDIT**: This was my first "solution" where I misinterpreted the problem and thought that $\gamma$ was supposed to work for all $n$, and not that $\gamma$ depended on $n$. Anyway the ideas are interesting and I thought it is good to leave it here:

First, note that it suffices to solve this for $n=2$.

Indeed, suppose $\gamma$ satisfies the inequality$\phantom{}^{(1)}$ for $n$, and take $n+1$ numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_n,y_{n+1}$ satisfying the hypotheses of the problem. We can assume all $x_i\neq 0$. Take $c=\frac{1}{x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}+x_nx_{n+1}}$. Then

$$c^nx_1\cdots x_nx_{n+1}=(cx_1)\cdots (cx_{n-1})(cx_nx_{n+1})\leq\gamma(cx_1y_1+\cdots+cx_{n-1}y_{n-1}+cx_nx_{n+1}(y_n+y_{n+1})),$$
Divide this inequality by $c$, use the fact that $c^{n-1}\geq 1$ and that $$x_nx_{n+1}(y_n+y_{n+1})\leq x_ny_n+y_{n+1}x_{n+1}$$
and conclude that
$$x_1\cdots x_nx_{n+1}\leq\gamma(x_1y_1+\cdots+x_{n+1}y_{n+1}).$$
So by induction, any $\gamma$ which makes the desired kind of inequality valid for $n=2$ will also work for all $n\geq 2$.

Now, for $n=2$, the only numbers $0\leq y_1,y_2\leq 1/2$ satisfying $y_1+y_2=1$ are $y_1=y_2=1/2$, and if $x_1,x_2\geq 0$ and $x_1+x_2=1$ then $x_2=1-x_1$. Thus we simply have to maximize the function
$$f(x)=\frac{x(1-x)}{\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}(1-x)}=2x(1-x)$$
The maximum is at $x=1/2$ (between the two roots $0$ and $1$), on which $f(1/2)=2\frac{1}{2}^2=\frac{1}{2}$, so $\gamma=\frac{1}{2}$ is the desired number.

---

<sub>(1) When I say that $\gamma$ "satisfies the inequality for $n$", I mean that $\gamma$ is a number such that for all $x_1,\ldots,x_n\geq 0$ with $\sum x_i=1$ and for all $0\leq y_1,\ldots,y_n\leq 1/2$ with $\sum y_1=$, we have $x_1\cdots x_n\leq\gamma(x_1y_1+\cdots+x_ny_n)$.</sub>

Comment: This is not correct since it is not the minimun for any $n$ exept the case $n=2$ the correct answare should be $\gamma=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}$. However your idea is interesting I'll take your way and try it again.

Comment: @WeijieChen Oh, damn! I misunderstood the problem... Anyway, I think I'll leave this answer here for the case anyone is interested, or misunderstands the problem as well

Comment: I preciate your help! I'll add a clarification for future misundertanding.

Comment: @WeijieChen I added an elementary (although long) solution.

Comment: It looks good. But what is the motivation for considering the funtion?

Comment: @WeijieChen it's because of the symmetries of the problem. We want to get rid of variables to simplify the problem, so the first step is to get rid of the $y_i$ (as done in the beginning). We end up with $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ in the left and $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the right. We don't have symmetry among all the $x_i$ anymore, but we have symmetries inside the sets $\{x_1,x_2\}$ and $\{x_3,\ldots,x_k\}$, which is also good. (cont...)

Comment: Starting with $x_1$ and $x_2$, we try to modify them in such a way that preserves the sum and increases the product (this is the function for $k=1$), and end up with only one variable. We manage to do that, and now deal with the remaining variables. We already know how to do it with only two variables, and we can try to use some inductive process. The therm "$\epsilon/k$" in the function is just to preserve the sum, and the same technique works. The rest is just usual calculations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45713/discussion-between-weijie-chen-and-luiz-cordeiro).